# About Persistent Storage, Should I turn on Persistent true on Client node if i only use atomic cache?

Tags: ignite

About Persistent Storage, Should I turn on Persistent true on Client node if i only use atomic cache?

```
<property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true">
```

I have several ignite client with RESTful of ignite turn on, to query remote several ignite servers, i know it's sure to keep the data safe when node corrupt, i need turn on persistent on server node, should i also turn on this
on my client node or i don't need turn it on as all my cache is atomic, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, client nodes do not store data. So, this parameter does not make much sense.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers